# Linux on my machine forgets screen brightness setting after login

Tags: brightness

I have an old Dell Latitude laptop and I have been running Linux on it for a few years without any problems.

But about a month ago, anytime I start the computer and log in, or do a screen lock and log back in, the screen brightness is at highest setting and I have to manually reduce the screen brightness using Windows key + down arrow.

I thought this was an issue with my distro but I then installed other distros eg Debian and it has the same issue.

So it seems to be an issue for any Linux distro that I use.

I went into BIOS and made sure that 1) Automatic screen brightness based on ambient light is NOT enabled, and 2) Set screen brightness to about 50%.

Since it seems to be an issue with any Linux distro, I thought I would post in this forum.

I realize it could be an issue with my laptop, but I am having trouble figuring that out.

Any help is much appreciated.